# Conway's Game of Life in Emacs Lisp

Tags: game-of-life, elisp

I decided it would be fun to implement [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life) (CGOL) in Emacs Lisp as my first elisp script.

My goals for the implementation were pretty simple

- Transform current buffer into the next generation of CGOL
- Just use max height/width of the current buffer (don't worry about overflowing the space, keep it bounded)
- Be able to specify which character means "alive", assume all others are dead

To implement this, I came up with the following

```lisp
(defun conway-current-buffer (alive-char)
  (interactive "cAlive-charater: ")

  (defun key (x y)
    (concat (number-to-string x) "-" (number-to-string y)))

  (defun pair-to-key (p)
    (concat (number-to-string (car p)) "-" (number-to-string (cadr p))))

  (defun neighbors (x y)
    (list
     (list (+ x 1) (+ y 1))
     (list (+ x 1) (- y 1))
     (list (- x 1) (- y 1))
     (list (- x 1) (+ y 1))

     (list (+ x 1) y)
     (list (- x 1) y)
     (list x       (- y 1))
     (list x       (+ y 1))))

  (defun alive-neighbor-count (x y state)
    (progn
      (setq alive-neighbors 0)
      (dolist (neighbor (neighbors x y))
        (if (gethash (pair-to-key neighbor) state)
            (setq alive-neighbors (+ 1 alive-neighbors))))
      alive-neighbors))

  (defun lives-on (x y state)
    (let ((alive-ns (alive-neighbor-count x y state))
          (alive (gethash (key x y) state nil)))
      (or (eq alive-ns 3) (and alive (eq alive-ns 2)))))

  (defun clear-buffer ()
    (kill-region (point-min) (point-max)))

  (defun render (height width state)
    (progn
      (clear-buffer)
      (setq y 0)
      (while (< y height)
        (progn
          (setq x 1)
          (while (<= x width)
            (if (gethash (key x y) state)
                (insert (char-to-string alive-char))
              (insert " "))
            (setq x (+ 1 x)))
          (setq y (+ 1 y))
          (if (< y height) (insert "\n"))))))

  (defun next-state (height width state)
    (progn
      (setq next (make-hash-table :test #'equal))
      (setq y 0)
      (while (< y height)
        (progn
          (setq x 0)
          (while (< x width)
            (if (lives-on x y state) (puthash (key x y) t next))
            (setq x (+ 1 x)))
          (setq y (+ 1 y))))
      next))

  (let ((text (buffer-string))
        (state (make-hash-table :test #'equal)))
    (progn
      (setq lines (split-string text "\n"))
      (setq width 0)
      (setq height (length lines))
      (setq y 0)
      (dolist (line lines)
        (progn
          (setq width (max width (length line)))
          (setq x 0)
          (dolist (c (split-string line ""))
            (progn
              (if (eq alive-char (string-to-char c)) (puthash (key x y) t state))
              (setq x (+ 1 x))))
          (setq y (+ 1 y)))
        )
      (render height width (next-state height width state)))))
```

## What I'm Looking For in a Review

- Please point out any beginner mistakes
- Am I scoping correctly (esp. with `setq`s and nested `defun`s)?
- Non-idiomatic code, easier functions to use
- Performance concerns - though I didn't necessarily strive for optimized, any tips are appreciated
- General suggestions

## "Bonus Points"

I know CR SE's not a Q&A site as much, so feel free to skip these, but

- Is this "good enough" to distribute as a package (i.e. is `interactive` all it takes?)
- Given I'm using spacemacs, where would I included this to be able to use it?
- How would one define a hash `:test` that uses `(x . y)` pairs instead of strings (e.g. `"x-y"`)?